# Flutter Camera Plugin Landscape Video on iPhone

Tags: flutter, video-capture

Video does not capture in the right orientation when running the Camera Plugin example app on my iPhone X in Landscape.
It works well in Portrait.

[image]

**pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  camera: ^0.4.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0
  video_player: ^0.10.0
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

**flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.1.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: do you mean the preview is not in the right orientation?  or the captured video is not in the right direction? or both?

Comment: Based on the image I uploaded the preview is rotated 90 degrees, and when is it played in the video player it is still rotated 90 degrees. I am going to save the video to Firebase and see the saved file.

Comment: Saved video taken in Portrait orientation, to Firebase and plays correctly as Portrait. Saved video taken in Landscape orientation, to Firebase and it plays as it looks in the image I uploaded, it is rotated 90 degrees and is in Portrait aspect ratio.

Comment: I downloaded the Landscape video and in Quicktime player I rotated left and the video looked normal landscape with the correct aspect ratio, so there is some mix up with the orientation.

Comment: try to set the preview to landscape first.  I'll post the widgets to set preview in landscape in the answer.

Comment: btw, before showing this page to capture video, did you run the code:    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);

Comment: I tried adding that to the void main() and it still captures the video rotated 90 degrees, but locks the screen to Landscape. My app needs to be in Portrait when the user captures text information, and I have it doing those screens, taking Photos with image_picker, saving data in SQFlite and syncing with a .Net application with a SQL Server backend. It's just the video capture that is not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

Till support lands in the official package, I have had success with `flutter_ffmpeg` to set proper metadata.

```dart
const int AV_LOG_ERROR = 16;

final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
_flutterFFmpeg.setLogLevel(AV_LOG_ERROR);

/// The :s:v:0 after -metadata is the stream specifier,
/// which just tells ffmpeg to which stream it should add the metadata.
/// :s stands for the streams of the input file,
/// :v selects video streams and the number is the stream index,
/// zero-based - so this will select the first video stream.
/// The -c option specifies the codec
/// to be used, with copy for just copying the streams, without re-encoding.
final String looselessConversion = '-i $videoPath.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 $videoPath-processed.mp4';

try {
  final int returnCode = await _flutterFFmpeg.execute(looselessConversion);

  if(returnCode == 0) {
    // delete the origina video file
    await File('$videoPath.mp4').delete();
  } else {
    throw _flutterFFmpeg.getLastCommandOutput();
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('video processing error: $e);
}
```

Because I am not encoding the video (just editing metadata) the process completes in less than 10ms for any length of a video file.

Comment: I wasn't able to turn my videos using your ffmpg script. But this one is working for me:  '-i $videoPath.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -c:a copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 $videoPath-processed.mp4'

Comment: And I only rotate iOS videos. Otherwise, Android videos would be turned not correctly

Comment: Don't forget that `flutter_ffmpeg` adds up ~ 120 MB to the size of your final APK

Comment: @KirillKarmazin our final production version is about 60 MB. Make sure you don't use the entire package. See https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg for options. In our case we are only pulling in `packages/flutter_ffmpeg_video_lts`.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave, try the following widgets to set the preview in landscape:

```
  Widget widTakePhoto2(context) {

       if (!ctlCamera.value.isInitialized) {

          return Container();

        }



    return Stack(

      children: <Widget>[

        RotatedBox(

          quarterTurns: 3,

          child: AspectRatio(

            aspectRatio: ctlCamera.value.aspectRatio,

            child: CameraPreview(ctlCamera),

          ),

        ),

        Center(child: Text(

            (gv.intHomeCameraCountDown > 0) ? gv.intHomeCameraCountDown.toString() : '',

            style: TextStyle(fontSize: sv.dblDefaultFontSize * 3, color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))

      ],

    );

  }
```

i.e. put the widget aspectratio inside a rotatedbox widget, this widget widtakephoto2 should be the 'body' of your scaffold widget.  and forget about the stack widget, I'm using stack to show 3, 2, 1 before taking the photo or video.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kenneth, but that results in a cosmetic change and just rotates the preview, but the video is still captured in the wrong orientation on the iPhone, I don't have a physical Android device to check and the Android Emulators I have tried get Gradle errors. The RotatedBox was also rotating the Preview in Portrait, so I added quarterTurns: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape ? 3 : 0,

Comment: ok, at least it solves the preview problem. I got the video capture in wrong direction (always wrong in first capture ONLY) in Android problem but it suddenly disappear and I didn't know why.  can you try to add (before the capture, but after await ctlCamera.initialize();):  await Thread.sleep(500);

Comment: i.e. after initialize the controller, wait 0.5 seconds before starting the video capture.  (This also solves the problem that just after the controller initialized: the first picture captured, or the first few ms of the video captured, is VERY DARK)

Comment: I have also tried  sleep(const Duration(milliseconds:500));   after the await controller.initialize();
(thread.sleep(500) is C# ?

Comment: can you try to Take a picture first and then start capture video right after taking the picture?  my previous orientation problem only happens in the first capture, the Second capture is correct.

Comment: await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);  Did you use 'await' to lock the ui to landscape?  then rotate the phone physically to landscape, press a button, init camera, wait 500 ms, take a picture, and finally capture a video.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have tried those methods and still the video is still rotated for 90 degrees in iOS